# how do i set a bool with key and make it like a switch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

i wanna make a script that opens photo mode by a key(in my case "e") and holds it in open state until i press the key (e) again and i can't because it keeps updating it the code:

```
If (Input.GetKey("e"))
      {
         Debug.Log("e");
         if (isphoto == true)
         {

             Debug.Log("true");
             MaxtimetoSwitch = 1;
             while (MaxtimetoSwitch >= 1)
             {
                 isphoto = false;
                 MaxtimetoSwitch = MaxtimetoSwitch - 1;


             }
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.Log("false");
             MaxtimetoSwitch = 1;
             while (MaxtimetoSwitch >= 1)
             {
                 isphoto = true;
                 MaxtimetoSwitch = MaxtimetoSwitch - 1;

             }
         }
         
             Debug.Log("false");
             MaxtimetoSwitch = 1;
             while (MaxtimetoSwitch >= 1)
             {
                 isphoto = true;
                 MaxtimetoSwitch = MaxtimetoSwitch - 1;

        }
```

Comment: You know that your `while` loops are all executed "immediately" within one single frame right?

Comment: @derHugo i tried to make it waitforseconds but it didn't work and i'll try this method instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)?

It returns `true` only in the **one frame** where the key goes down. You don't have to care about the input every frame as you are just interested in single click events.

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    { 
        // invert bool flag
        isphoto = !isphoto; 
        
        // TODO: Open or close photo window according to isPhoto
        // e.g.
        photoWindow.SetActive(isphoto);
    }
}
```

or if your goal is to **wait** until the key was pressed for a certain amount of time then do e.g.

```
// Adjust in the Inspector
[SerializeField] private float switchThreshold = 1f;

private float timePressed;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    { 
        // first frame -> reset counter
        timePressed = 0f;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && timePressed < switchThreshold)
    {
        // increase counter by the time passed since last frame
        timePressed += Time.deltaTime;
    
        // once counter exceeds
        if(timePressed >= switchThreshold)
        {
            isphoto = !isphoto; 
            
            // TODO: Open or close photo window according to isPhoto
            // e.g.
            photoWindow.SetActive(isphoto);
        }
    }
}
```